# C# Form with buttons and dynamic forms beside those buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, dialog

I am using Windows form in C# and i am trying to create one single form dialog that will be responsible displaying other dialogs within the boundary of it's dialog. To do that i tried Tab Control and it worked well and i can create different types of form in tab control easily without opening any separate forms.

but the problem is i don't want to use Tab control , I have some buttons on the main form at left side and clicking those buttons i want to display separate forms beside those buttons. I searched google but did not find any example like that nor i am able to find any control as this. My application is very simple one dialoge with left side buttons and on right side i want to show different forms based on those buttons... C# is not my native language but now i have to work on it and require help.

Kindly check the attached image for more information

[image]

Comment: `i don't want to use Tab control` Why not? You do know that you can set the tab control to display buttons rather than tabs, right?

Comment: because my requirement is not to use the tabs but single dialog like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each page could be an instance of Panel, then show/hide the Panel instances according to which button is clicked....make them all the same size, shape, and position ;)

Comment: that means i need to create all the forms of panels in the same parent form or i should create separate forms and adjust them inside panel dynamically?

Comment: Either approach would work I believe, it depends on what you are more comfortable with. For something straight forward like this I would create all the panels ahead of time, and simply show the appropriate one.